# Not able to insert data in a table having foreign key using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

i have made 2 tables
2nd table consists of foreign key which references primary key of first table 
2nd table consists of 3 fields id(primary key),order no,fid
i am using the following command

insert into table2 (order no,fid)
values(1,(select id from table1 where name='abc');

error in sql syntax`enter code here`

Comment: what is the full error message?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order no,fid)values(1,(select id from table 2 where name='abc'))' at line 1

Comment: i am using mysql query browser

Comment: because you have a space in between the `order` and `no`. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  You must quote it using backticks: `` `order no` ``.

Also, you should probably use MySQL's [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`order no`, fld)
SELECT 1,id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'abc'
```

Comment: yeah thanks its working what mistake was i making could u please tell me??

Comment: @user1690808: As @JW. [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628150/not-able-to-insert-data-in-a-table-having-foreign-key-using-mysql#comment20431472_14628150) [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628150/not-able-to-insert-data-in-a-table-having-foreign-key-using-mysql#comment20431502_14628181), and as stated in my answer above, you need to quote `order no`.

Comment: insert into table2 (`order no`,fid) select 2,id from table1 where name='anubhav';                                                                    im getting following error now  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`table2`, CONSTRAINT `fid` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`))

Comment: @user1690808: It looks like you have created your foreign key reference incorrectly; either you want `fid` to reference `table1.id` or else you should be inserting `table1.id` into `table2.id`.

Answer (score 0):

you lack extra closing parenthesis

```
insert into table2 (`order no`,fid) 
values(1,(select id from table1 where name='abc' LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: i made a mistake while posting my qs ,i did that also but still error persists

Comment: because you have a space in between the `order` and `no`. updated.

Answer (score 0):

insert into `table2` (`order no`,`fid`) values(1,(select id from table1 where name='abc');

Edited...
could be the problem line:
he error is Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (abc/demo1, CONSTRAINT fid FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES demo (id))

it shud be (abc/demo1,CONSTRAINT fid FOREIGN KEY (**fid**) REFERENCES demo (id))

Comment: order and table are reserved words by mySQL. u cannot name a column using a reserved word. if u do u hv to Quote it by parentheses.. if u had named your column orderno it wud do but u named it `order no`.. order is used by SQL to do a order by.. nice going champ..

Comment: ok i got it but when i am using ur statement it is giving an error

Comment: the error is                                                             Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`abc/demo1`, CONSTRAINT `fid` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `demo` (`id`))

Comment: INSERT INTO table2 (`order no`, fld)
SELECT 1,id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'abc' when i am using this statement its working

Comment: the constraints are on table demo and demo1 .. while u r inserting in table2 after selecting from table1. am i missing something !

Comment: FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES demo (id)) shud it not be FOREIGN KEY (fid) REFERENCES demo (id)) ...... change to fid from id...

Comment: demo1 is same as table 2 and demo is same as table1 i used table1 and table2 to post my question ,yesterday it was working and now it's not

Comment: yeah i made the changed,i made a silly mistake when i made a table now i have rectified it thanks